# Eclipse Running OK on Mountain Lion?

Tags: eclipse, osx-lion

Simple question. Has anyone had issues running Eclipse on Mountain Lion. More specifically, I'm using Helios Service Release 2 and Pydev. Don't want to upgrade if this will break.

Answer (score 1):

I have no issues running eclipse on mountain lion, apart from the occasional corrupt workspace, but this happens generally with eclipse on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can live with the usual hiccups when you upgrade. But can't afford downtime with Eclipse.

Comment: If you cant afford downtime then why on earth are you ever upgrading so close to the release of a new OS upgrade?  Atleast wait a month or two to see how everyone is getting on with it then decide to go for it but dont be silly and upgrade on a main machine that you rely on for work, not unless it provides you with something that is utterly essential.

Comment: When you develop for Android and you want to click open implementation  in context menu, it is hidden by horizontal scroll bar. :/